# How do you understand these hows?

Tags: free-relative-clauses

> "I lost my eye in the line of duty. What do you think of that?" he
>   said with a pride that made me all the angrier.
>   "I don't give a
>   damn **how** you lost it as long as you keep it hidden."
>  (Ralph
>   Ellison, Invisible Man)
>
> Disgusted that the Slytherins had lost, he had tried to get everyone
>   laughing at **how** a wide-mouthed tree frog would be replacing Harry
>   as Seeker next.   
> (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

In the two how-clauses, it seems that ‘how’ takes an adverbial function in the clause and the whole how-clause has the nominal function as the object and the complement of preposition respectively. In this case, do you think these two functions at a time when you read these, or anything else process happens in your brains? (For my better understanding, would you let me know the ‘how’s’ meaning in the contexts?)

Comment: In both these examples *how* is (just about) replaceable by **the way**, but in #1 **what way** works better idiomatically, as does **the way in which** in #2. In other constructions ("How old are you?") it's more *to what **extent*** rather than *by what **method** / in what **way***

Comment: @FumbleFingers: One may also say that the first example has an "about" implied: "I don't give a damn about how you lost it...".  Given that, "I don't give a damn about the way in which you lost it" works, which bears out your theory that "how" replaces "the way in which".

Comment: @BobRodes: I agree that native speakers naturally imagine the word "about" being implied before "the way" if we use that instead of "how" in #1, but I think that's just a quirk of grammar (in principle we could accept "about **how**" anyway). I'm just trying to get across to OP how we understand **how** in his two constructions, given that few of us naturally think in terms of "object" or "complement of preposition".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This questions casts a spotlight on the futility of trying to pin such widely used words down to a particular "part of speech". The dictionaries will tell you that *how* is an "adverb" - perhaps an "interrogative adverb" or a "relative adverb" - but in these two instances *how* is neither of these. It is the head of what grammarians call ***free relative clauses***. These clauses exhibit the following characteristics:

1. They are headed by—*what shall we call them?* Particle *seems to be replacing* adverb *as the stock wastebasket term, and at least does not invite any confusion with entirely unrelated uses, so*—These phrases are headed by particles which in other contexts act as interrogatives: *who, what, which, why, when, where, whether, how*, or combinations of these with *-ever*. A brief and not entirely satisfying discussion of *Free Relatives* in McCawley 1998, 13.c., gives good reasons for identifying these particles with interrogatives, and less-good reasons for calling them **relativizers**.
2. They act as noun phrases. As you say, the *how* clause in your second example acts as the object of the preposition *at*. In your first example, the *how* clause acts as the direct object of the phrasal verb *give a damn*. If this is confusing, substitute a more conventional verb and the structure becomes clear:

   > I don't see how you lost it.
   >   It doesn't matter how you lost it.
   >   Don't tell me how you lost it.
   >   That's not how you lost it.
3. They have the same internal structure as relative clauses, with the head particle seeming to stand for a term omitted from the remainder of the clause. This is why these clauses are characterized as *relative*. It is a singularly unhappy use of the term, since the  heading particle is unrelated to any antecedent—which is why the clauses are further characterized as *free*, not "bound" to an antecedent.

The Comments by FumbleFingers and Bob Rodes discuss how to understand what *how* means here. *The way in which* works adequately, or *the manner in which*. But do not misunderstand their casual use of "replace". *How* does not "replace" these paraphrases or "stand for them".<sup>†</sup> In both your examples *how* signifies an account or narrative of what was done rather than the way or manner in which it was done—as it is used, for example, in titles:

> How the Camel Got His Hump
>   How Robin Hood Came to be an Outlaw
>   How Stella Got Her Groove Back

---

<sup>†</sup> If anything, it's the other way around. *How* was already used in this way in Old English, long before *Wh-* relatives and pied piping came into the language.

Comment: "replace" : Can I say that 'how' can be replaced by 'on that of how~"?

Comment: @Listenever Not really. *How* doesn't "mean" anything so much as it signals the mode in which the clause "means". "How the Camel Got His Hump" is the title of a story in which the camel gets his hump. "I don't give a damn how you lost it" means "I'm not interested in the action of losing it, all I care about is that it is lost".

Comment: How they call the structure is dependent upon, I guess, how they see the structure. (1) Downing calls it ‘Nominal Relatives’ by the clauses’ function. (2) They call it Free Relatives because there’s none antecedents.(MaCawley) (3) They call it Fused Relatives because the WH contains the meaning of antecedents. (Cambridge Grammar, p.1068)

Comment: In OP’s second case, ‘how’ can be simply replaced by ‘that’?

Comment: @No, because 1) a *that* clause would signify the fact  of replacing, not the process or action 2) a *that* clause doesn't act as the object of a preposition.

Comment: Then how about this: ‘how’, in second case, can be replaced by ‘the action that’?

Comment: @Listenever It can, but nobody would, because a) "action" here is a technical term drawn from dramatic criticism and b) how people say it is *how*. [But in b) the first *how* is FumbleFingers' "the way that".] It's just the idiom: you can surround it with paraphrases, but you can't hit it exactly.